# Declaration of type in parentheses when assigning

Tags: objective-c, syntax, types, casting

Sometimes I see examples code like this:

```
RootViewController *rootViewController = (RootViewController *)[navigationController topViewController];
```

Where `RootViewController` is a specific class that inherits from `UITableViewController` and the object `navigationController` is an instance of the class `UINavigationController`.

I want to know what is the `(RootviewController *)` just after the `=`.

Is that a test for the type before assignation to pointer `*rootViewController` or just information for the compiler to avoid a warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a cast.

All I can say is that the object gotten with `[navigationController topViewController]` is not of type `rootViewController`, and can't be assigned to `rootViewController` without a "transformation".

It's like if you do:

```
int32 nbr = (int32)myInt64;
```